# PHP Get siteurl dynamically

Tags: php

I am trying to get the siteurl **without hardcoding** and store it in a constant inside of a configuration file, so that I can use it within my scripts irrespective of the nesting/nested folders. This configuration file is stored in a folder within the main installation directory of the website.

**Example:**

Install website on www.mydomain.com

Configuration file located in www.mydomain.com/my_folder/configuration.php

Want to declare a constant in configuration.php file so that it always gets the installed path dynamically without having to hardcode it. So `define("MY_SITE_URL", ???? )`

What should be in the place of the ???? in the code above so that it works even if my main website is installed within nested folders?

**Examples: All the pages will contain the same configuration.php at the beginning of the file as a require**

***Install website in Site 1:***

Root directory of website: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/**

Location of configuration: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/my_folder/configuration.php**

Sub folder: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/index.php**

echoing MY_SITE_URL in index.php should give www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/

Sub folder: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/index.php**

Location of configuration: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/my_folder/configuration.php**

echoing MY_SITE_URL in index.php should give www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/

***Install website in Site 2:***

Root directory of website: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/**

Location of configuration: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/my_folder/configuration.php**

Sub folder: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/1/index.php**

echoing MY_SITE_URL in index.php should give www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/

Sub folder: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/1/2/index.php**

Location of configuration: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/my_folder/configuration.php**

echoing MY_SITE_URL in index.php should give www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/

Please note that the TLD can change. That means, installing the website on www.mydomain.tk, www.mydomai.org, www.mydomain.net, www.mydomain.co.ca etc. should not render the code useless.

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**

I have tried to put together a script. I almost got there, but not 100%. Here it is:

```
function domain_url()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]))
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") 
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    //Remove any GET params from url
    $remmove_get = strtok($pageURL, '?');
    //Removes trailing slash only at the end of string. This slash is received only when accessing a page within sub folders.
    $pageURL = preg_replace('{/$}', '', $remmove_get);

    //Remove page name
    $pageURL = dirname($pageURL);

    return $pageURL;
}
define("MY_SITE_URL", domain_url().'/');
```

**Issue with my current code:**

Running the code on www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/ and www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/ gives MY_SITE_URL as www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/ and this is correct.

But when I run the code on www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/index.php, echoing MY_SITE_URL gives me **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/** when in fact I wanted: **www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/**

How to solve this?

Comment: If you want to get to that without hardcoding, then you need to define the logic first. I don't see any logic there that one could use as a basic for code. Is there such logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want the 2nd directory then you can use

```
$boom = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$domain_url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/'.$boom[1].'/'.$boom[2];
echo $domain_url;
```

If the site is ever not in the 2nd directory you can use: (this code should be a bit more concise). Just replace site1 with the name of the site

```
$site_search = "site1";
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domain_url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, $site_search)+strlen($site_search));;
echo $domain_url;
```

**Update**
This will get the url for everything before /my_folder

```
$domain_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domain_url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '/my_folder'));
define("MY_SITE_URL", domain_url().'/');
```

On a side-note, you should try the [Code-Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) framework. The framework makes this sort of thing extremely easy.

Comment: Hi, what does **always want the 2nd directory** and **If the site is ever not in the 2nd directory** mean?

Comment: Results of the 2nd highlighted code of your answer (lengthy one): www.mydomain.com/test.php gives www.mydomain.com/test.php; www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/ gives www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/; www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/ gives www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/ So it seems that this code is no different from what I had in terms of functionality.

Comment: Results of the 1st highlighted code of your answer (short one): www.mydomain.com/test.php gives www.mydomain.com/test.php; www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/ gives www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/; www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/ gives www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/; This code is closer to what I want but that breaks unless its 2 folders deep. So if I use this code in the root folder of the website or just within the first sub folder of the website, the code will break. How can this be fixed to ensure that regardless of where its installed, it always gets the correct path?

Comment: Did you set the $site_search variable? That is used to stop the loop when it reaches the site name you are looking for. Second directory means www.yoursite.com/first_directory/Second_Directory. So if your site names are always the second directory the first code will print www.yoursite.com/first_directory/second_directory  no matter how many extra /directories you have. The bottom code you set $site_search = "site1" or whatever is the name of the site you are trying to get the url for. Do you understand what the code is doing or do you need some instructions?

Comment: If I set  $site_search = "site1", it works on www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/ www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/; But the very same code, when used on www.mydomain.com without any changes, breaks. It gives www. I was trying to avoid having to change the code, regardless of the installation directory i.e. main root directory of website or in folders/sub-folders. Can this be fixed without having to make changes in the code every time?

Comment: I was thinking if we can grab the complete absolute url to the configuration.php file, we can easily get what we are trying to accomplish. So it would be: www.mydomain.com/my_folder/configuration.php www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/my_folder/configuration.php www.mydomain.com/demos/site2/my_folder/configuration.php; If you notice the path to the config file will remain same i.e. /my_folder/configuration.php. Only the actual installation part will change. So if we can grab the complete URL to confguration.php & str_replace my_folder/configuration.php, we should have our desired URL. What say?

Comment: Yep. That works too. Would have been nice to kb pi a that beforehand in the question :)

Comment: kb pi a? Sorry, don't know what that means. I got that thought as I was experimenting with the solutions. There are some differences in the way the same constant works on Apache & IIS Server, so ultimately that's what I felt would be the perfect way to get it.

Comment: Know* my phone is stupid. Yep go do a str replace if you already know a difinitive endpoint /my_folder

Comment: I am stuck with trying to get the absolute path for the configuration.php file. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll add a revision to my answer give me a moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define('PROTOCOL', array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://');
define('DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('FOLDER', (dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == '/' ? null : dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/');
define('BASE_URL', PROTOCOL . DOMAIN . dirname(FOLDER));
```

Those 4 constants should cover what you are looking for. I wrote about this a little more here in this post - http://bit.ly/MPls0E

Comment: This gives `www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/` when I run `www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/1/2/index.php`. I was expecting to receive `www.mydomain.com/demos/site1/`. Any changes?

Comment: Maybe change FOLDER to dirname(FOLDER) in the 4th line to go up a directory?

Comment: Won't that break again when even more folders are nested?

Answer (score 0):

While I know this is a VERY old post it started me down the direction of the answer. here is my results. I hope this helps someone in the future.

This gives you your install directory:

```
$path = 'FindMe.locate';
while(! realpath($path)){
$path = '../' . $path;
}
define('DIR_FS_ROOT', dirname(realpath($path)) . '/');
```

For the web address I simply used:

```
define('HTTP_ROOT', 'http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ':8080/');
```

This gives me the base directory then I simply add what ever file I am looking for.

```
echo HTTP_ROOT . 'images/logo.png';
echo DIR_FS_ROOT . 'images/logo.png';
```

that way you can use the code on the server side or the client side and none of it has to be hard coded. :-)